# What params should i pass in id so that my subdocument is saved to a specific parent id?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, next.js, mongodb-query

This is a test api I used this api to save subdocument to parent document. It is working.

```
import initDB from '../../helper/initDB';
import User from '../../models/addUser';

initDB()

export default async (req, res) => {
  (req.method)
  {
    "POST"
    await handler(req, res)
  }
}
const handler = async (req, res) => {
  if (req.method == 'POST') {
    console.log(req.body)
    const user = await User.findByIdAndUpdate({ _id: '62716cc5cd028105a46b1a48' })
    const { rsph, rcyl, raxis, lsph, lcyl, laxis, add, frame, lens } = req.body
    const order = { rsph, rcyl, raxis, lsph, lcyl, laxis, add, frame, lens };
    user.orders.push(order);
    await user.save()
    res.status(200).json({ success: "success" })
  }
  else {
    res.status(400).json({ error: "this method is not required" })
  }
}
```

But i want this api to work in a way so that the subdocument gets saved to the id which i have opened on the browser

Link to my Github repo :-

https://github.com/Sarab71/Git-optics

Comment: From which page on your frontend are you making request on this api endpoint?

Comment: Thank you so much for replying, am making request from this page
https://github.com/Sarab71/Git-optics/blob/main/pages/user/%5Bid%5D.js